# We have been dating each other? or We have been dating together?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/together_1?q=together)

> together= with each other

Now, we got the structure "**to talk with somebody**":

*I talked with him.*

*He talked with me.*

*We talked with each other.*

*We talked together.*

However, sometimes, we don't need "**with**" as in "**date somebody**".

*I dated her.*

*She dated me.*

*We dated with each other.*---> this violates the structure "**date somebody**" without "**with**"

*We dated together.* = *We dated with each other.*----> this violates the structure "**date somebody**"

*We dated each other.*---> this seems ok, but I am not sure.

I don't know whether the "**with**" in "**talk with**" is the same as the "**with**" in "**with together**".

Answer (score 1):

You can also say "We talked" and "I talked to him" - so you don't absolutely need "with" in this case.

For dating, I would say "I dated him" or "We dated" - dating is an action that absolutely already implies two people, so adding "together" sounds redundant. "We dated with each other" sounds very very odd. "We dated each other" is a little odd, but could sound okay under certain circumstances. For instance, if there is confusion about who dated who. Example: Say as you are now dating person A, and person B is dating person C, and you say "We (you and person B) dated each other back in high school" - in other words, you're emphasizing that you dated EACH OTHER, not your current boyfriend/girlfriend, during high school